# Android Room: Handling Relations with LiveData

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

So I have two models(tables), `WordGroups` and `Words`, and the relation between them is one to many.
So my models and `Dao` look like:

```
@Entity
public class WordGroup {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @Ignore
    private List<Word> words;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Word> getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public void setWords(List<Word> words) {
        this.words = words;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Word {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @ForeignKey(entity = WordGroup.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "wordGroupId")
    private int wordGroupId;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getWordGroupId() {
        return wordGroupId;
    }

    public void setWordGroupId(int wordGroupId) {
        this.wordGroupId = wordGroupId;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Dao
public interface Dao {

    @Query("select * from WordGroup where id = :id")
    LiveData<WordGroup> selectWordGroupById(int id);

    @Query("select * from WordGroup")
    LiveData<List<WordGroup>> selectAllWordGroups();

    @Query("select * from Word where wordGroupId = :wordGroupId")
    LiveData<List<Word>> selectWordsByWordGroupId(int wordGroupId);
}
```

now I have a method that selects a `WordGroup` and also sets its `Word`s using `Transformations`:

```
public LiveData<WordGroup> getWordGroupWithWords(int id) {
    LiveData<WordGroup> wordGroupLiveData = dao.selectWordGroupById(id);

    LiveData<WordGroup> wordGroupWithWordsLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(wordGroupLiveData, inputWordGroup -> {
        LiveData<List<Word>> wordsLiveData = dao.selectWordsByWordGroupId(inputWordGroup.getId());

        LiveData<WordGroup> outputWordGroupsLiveData = Transformations.map(wordsLiveData, inputWords -> {
            inputWordGroup.setWords(inputWords);
            return inputWordGroup;
        });

        return outputWordGroupsLiveData;
    });

    return wordGroupWithWordsLiveData;
}
```

now I want to write a method that selects all the `WordGroup`s that also sets their `Word`s for each `WordGroup`. the signature of the method should be something like:

```
public LiveData<List<WordGroup>> getAllWordGroupsWithWords();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried a little bit more and I came up with this solution with the help of `MediatorLiveData`:

```
public LiveData<List<WordGroup>> getAllWordGroupsWithWords() {
    LiveData<List<WordGroup>> wordGroupsLiveData = dao.selectAllWordGroups();
    LiveData<List<WordGroup>> outputWordGroups = Transformations.switchMap(wordGroupsLiveData, inputWordGroups -> {
        MediatorLiveData<List<WordGroup>> wordGroupsMediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        for (WordGroup wordGroup : inputWordGroups) {
            wordGroupsMediatorLiveData.addSource(dao.selectWordsByWordGroupId(wordGroup.getId()), words -> {
                wordGroup.setWords(words);
                wordGroupsMediatorLiveData.postValue(inputWordGroups);
            });
        }

        return wordGroupsMediatorLiveData;
    });

    return outputWordGroups;
}
```

now it is exactly the way I wanted, but there are some big problems.

- First it will call the observer many times if you use the method `setValue` on your `MediatorLiveData`, I could make it call the observer fewer times by using `postValue`
- Second even if you only change one word, it will call the observer for each `wordGroup` again!

Of Course it is not the most optimized solution but it does work. I am really open to suggestions and improvements.

Comment: check out this article https://medium.com/@rezabigdeli6/android-room-handling-relations-using-livedata-2d892e40bd53